# Drupal special menu items anchor

Tags: jquery, html, drupal, anchor

Not to sure where I am going wrong?
Installed and downloaded special menu items module. 
for the  tag = < a href="#" >. which is what I want seeing I want an anchor.

My anchor is "test"
For Path of a menu item in menu I put < nolink >test

In theory it should be url/#test

However I get "The path '< nolink > test' is either invalid or you do not have access to it."

If I just insert < nolink > I get a link that looks like this. url/#.

**So why can't I have the syntax < nolink >test to equal url/#test ?**

Answer (score 0):

With the [Special Menu Items module](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items), you can define `<voidX>` elements here :

```
/admin/config/user-interface/void_menu
```

[image]

Then you can use them as menu link path (`<void2>`...) and get the corresponding anchors in your menu (editing the menu link) :

```
/admin/structure/menu/item/[item_id]/edit
```

[image]

See attached screenshots for more details (sorry, it's in french).

Hope it helps, good luck !